# Запрос на выборку данных sql

Tags: mysql, sql, access, ms-access

## Для каждой должности сотрудников подсчитать число сотрудников и число заказов.

пока я мучаюсь с выводом должности и количеством сотрудников для каждой должности. 
Вот что выводиться...

Naimenovanie...........Kolichestvo

официант/курьер....5

[image: Dolzhnosti]

[image: Sotrudniki]

[image: FormirovaneiZakaza]

```
SELECT
  Dolzhnosti.Naimenovanie,
  COUNT(Sotrudniki.Kod_dolzhnosti) AS Kolichestvo
FROM
  Dolzhnosti
INNER JOIN
 (FormirovanieZakaza
  INNER JOIN
    Sotrudniki
  ON
    FormirovanieZakaza.Kod_sotrudnika = Sotrudniki.Kod_sotrudnika)
ON
  Dolzhnosti.Kod_dolzhnosti = Sotrudniki.Kod_dolzhnosti
GROUP BY
  Dolzhnosti.Naimenovanie;
```

Comment: count() от любого not null поля дает вам количество записей. количество сотрудников вы так не получите. Если бы у вас был не access я бы сказал что надо использовать count(distinct код-сотрудника) что бы получить количество уникальных кодов. но у вас так нельзя, так что для получения количества придется делать отдельный подзапрос, только в таблицу сотрудников, не помножая это на заказы

Comment: @Mike буду думать((

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
  Dolzhnosty.Kod_dolzhnosty,
  COALESCE(T.kolichestvo_sotr, 0) as kolichestvo_sotr, 
  COUNT(*) as kolichestvo_zakazov
FROM Dolzhnosty 
  --LEFT нужны для того, чтобы не потерять должности, у которых нет сотрудников 
  --или есть сотрудники, которые не формировали заказы.
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Kod_dolzhnosty, COUNT(*) as kolichestvo_sotr
    FROM Sotrudniki
    GROUP BY Kod_dolzhnosty
  ) as T ON Dolzhnosty.Kod_dolzhnosty = T.Kod_dolzhnosty
  LEFT JOIN Sotrudniki ON Dolzhnosty.Kod_dolzhnosty = Sotrudniki.Kod_dolzhnosty
  LEFT JOIN FormirovanieZakaza ON FormirovanieZakaza.Kod_sotrudnika = Sotrudniki.Kod_sotrudnika
GROUP BY Dolzhnosty.Kod_dolzhnosty
```